# help_text - Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to add help text to the form:

```
investigation_title = forms.CharField(
    error_messages={'required': 'Please provide an Investigation Title'},
    help_text = 'Help text...',
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(InvestigationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    ...
    self.helper.help_text_inline = True
    ...
```

But like this the help text is render below the field box. How to move the help text to the right side of the field box, position as it shows in the picture in the red rectangle?  [image]

template:

```
<div class="card-body">
   <form method="post" class="form" novalidate="novalidate">
       {% crispy form %}
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you set `self.helper.error_text_inline = True` by any chance? Also show the part of the template where you render the form

Comment: No I didn't set ```self.helper.error_text_inline = True```. I will look in the crispy form doc to see what that does. I updated the question with the template where the form is rendered. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: `error_text_inline` and `help_text_inline` are properties on the helper class such that setting one will unset the other, so only one can be `True` at a time which is why I asked that in the comment.